# Accessing VirtualBox Windows 10 IIS localhost from Mac host

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, iis, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I have an ASP.NET project running in Windows 10 VirtualBox. While the Visual Studio project is running on localhost, I'd like to be able to access it from my Mac host operating system, however I get a 'Not found' error when entering it in the browser. How can I fix this?

Steps I've taken:

1. Set virtual machine Network Adapter to 'Bridged'
2. Started Visual Studio project, which runs on `localhost:27013`
3. Got the IP address of the Windows 10 Virtual Machine
4. Entered that IP address on the Mac host machine
5. Received 'Not found error'