# Accessing VirtualBox local host from Mac

Tags: macos, localhost, virtual-machine, virtualbox, virtualhost

I have a mac computer. On it I have installed a windows virtual machine via virtual box. On my windows machine i've got my project set up. What I would like to know, is how I can see the local host from the virtual machine on my mac. I have tried setting up the network settings to bridged adapter and typing the ip address of my VM on my mac browser, but that does not work.

Most of the answers I see are for users wanting to access the a localhost of their mac on the vm... I am looking for an answer that states the otherway around. 
it's a repeat question of [Accessing VirtualBox Windows 10 IIS localhost from Mac host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42755075/accessing-virtualbox-windows-10-iis-localhost-from-mac-host) but no one has answered this yet.

Any help is appreciated, i've spent hours looking for a working answer with no luck yet.

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by *"see the localhost"*? Do you want to be able to ping it? ssh into it? See some directories on it?

Comment: I ust want to be able to open it in my browser

Comment: Your real computer is a Mac and you have a virtual Windows machine installed on your Mac? You want to use Internet Explorer or some other web browser in the Windows VM to see the pages your Mac is serving? What is your Mac's IP address? What is your Windows IP address? What did you type in the Internet Explorer address bar? Can you ping your Mac from the Windows VM? Can you see the webpages your Mac is serving from the Mac itself?

Comment: its the other way around. I am serving my project on a windows vm and would like to see it on my mac.

Comment: pretty much want to do the opposite of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1261975/addressing-localhost-from-a-virtualbox-virtual-machine?rq=1